# Why does the command GOTO atack1 not result in executing the code below line :attack1 on batch file execution?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've started to learn batch/shell a while ago. and I started to make a text based rpg called bpg. anyways, I poured a day into making the basic structure of it and then I found out the cmd closes when I use the attack trigger. I ran over it a million times, but can't find anything wrong with it. Please help.

The batch file can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8r7cs0tvo8qhs8/bpg.bat?dl=0

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
if not "%1" == "max" start /MAX cmd /c %0 max & exit/b
title BPG 1 A batch of monsters
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
color 2

:menu
cls
echo  ______   _______   _______
echo I  ___ \ I  ____ I I ____  \
echo I I   I II I    II I I    \/
echo I  __ I  I  _____I I I ____
echo I I  \ \ I I       I I \_  I
echo I I___I II I       I I___I I
echo I______/ I_/       I_______I A BATCH OF MONSTERS
echo.
echo.
echo 1) begin
echo.
echo 2) exit
echo.
set /p c=bpg:

if "%c%" == "1" goto new
if "%c%" == "2" exit
goto menu

:new
set health=100
set enemyhealth=30
set playerdmg=10
set monsterdmg=10
goto home

:home
cls
echo --------------------
echo   Welcome to BPG
echo --------------------
echo (noobs can f off)
echo.
echo 1) Battle
echo 2) Menu
echo.

set /p c=bpg

if "!c!" == "1" goto encounter1
if "!c!" == "2" goto menu
goto home

:encounter1
cls
echo --------------------
echo You: %health%
echo Enemy: %enemyhealth%
echo --------------------
echo.
echo 1) attack
echo.
echo 2) flee
echo.
set /p c=bpg
if "!c!" == "1" goto atack1
if "!c!" == "2" goto home
goto encounter1

:attack1
set /a !health!-=!monsterdmg!
set /a !monsterhealth!-=!playerdmg!
if !monsterhealth! lss 0 goto win
goto encounter

:win
cls
echo.
echo --------------------
echo You Win!
echo --------------------
echo              _.oood"""""""booo._
echo          _.o""      _____    . ""o._
echo        oP"  _.ooo""""   """"oIo._. "Yo
echo      o8   oP  _.-":          I I"._. .8o
echo     d'  o8',-"    :          I I/  ,\. .b
echo    d'  d.-"      :           I I: (( .\
echo   8'  d' """"":  :           I I  II\_/. .8
echo  8   8'      :  :       I)   _ I  II I.I   8
echo ,8  8        :  :     /)I \ II I\_II I I8  8.
echo 8' ,8       :  :      " /_) I.:' I I I I8. .8
echo 8  8'       :  :        _ _-'  \ ' __   __  8
echo 8  8       :  :         \I__ I  I I  I I 8I 8
echo 8  8.      :  :         II   I  I I-:' I 8I 8
echo 8. .8     /   I      __/ I__ I__I I  \ I__I,8
echo 8  8   .'    \     /     __ . . . . . .8LL8'
echo  8   8.'       -. (    ,'  .. I I ,-I8  8
echo   8.(__________dd_) \__/ '  0I...: I: (8 ,8
echo    Y.  Y.                    I :/I I,\I. .P
echo     Y.  "8.          .,o     I I I,I".  ,P
echo      "8.  "Yo_               I IpI". ,8"
echo        "Y_   "ooo.__   __.ooI". . _P"
echo          '"oo_     """""    . _oo""'
echo               ."""boooooood"""'.
echo.
echo.
pause
```

Comment: Thanks so much man! I cant believe that was the case , I hardly got any sleep last night cos this was bugging me, thank alot man, really appreciated

Comment: Please do us a favour: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40573891/edit) your post and provide a **specific question title**!!

Comment: @asxhipfl XD soz about that but the questions been resolved so its g

Comment: running it *once* with `echo on` does help much more than running it *a million times*. Would have given you `Label not found` as last line and `if "1" == "1" goto atack1` as last but one line.

Answer (score 0):

```
if "!c!" == "1" goto atack1
```

Look for the million-and-first time at this command.

Now - why wouldn't it reach the label ":at**t**ack1"

And if you ever reach that label,

```
set /a !health!-=!monsterdmg!
```

will subtract the contents of `monsterdmg` from the variable whose name is (the contents of `health`)

This error is repeated on other lines.

What's the obsession with `!var!`? You only need `!var!` when you are dealing with values that are changing within a code block - normally a loop. The syntax works at other times, but beware - it may have unforseen side-effects. Better to stick with `%var%` unless you *need* to use the `!var!` form.

Comment: Thank's mate im a dummy for not realising that typo and thanks for the input on the `%var` instead of `!var!`